# MySQL Table Join inconsistencies

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL statement which Joins 3 tables and then produces some results.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v1zExsp4ZVnnq1hQYJKcXY/0

PROBLEM: DB Fiddle actually gives me the correct results BUT My Database: Version: 10.0.38-MariaDB - Gives different results.

Both DBs show all 48 rows when the `sale_category='Non-Productive'` filter is removed.

BUT - Only DB Fiddle filters correctly to 15 rows of data when the `sale_category='Non-Productive'` filter is present.

My MariaDB filters incorrectly resulting in 32 rows of data. (see attached)

[image: Incorrect]

My database is displaying results which should be filtered (e.g. any row with sale_type=CUSTOMER) BUT is showing them as 'Non-Productive' and I have no idea why (especially after testing in DB Fiddle and seeing desired results)

1. Why is it so?
2. Is there a more efficient SQL query?

Comment: [MariaDB-10.3 fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=37adb738acc4d042397288beee8af948) returns the same 15 rows as MariaDB-10.2 and MySQL-8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your data for unprod_hrs=0, there is no matches for the 'Non-Productive' sales type:

```
SELECT tech,name,rd.rate,unprod_hrs,st.sale_category
FROM ReportData rd
INNER JOIN SaleTypes st
   ON st.sale_type=rd.name
WHERE report_id='165141' AND unprod_hrs=0 AND rd.line_type=2;
```

MariaDB is returning incorrect results in your version 10.0.38

Also the two JOINS on ReportHeader can be removed as they aren't used in the query.